# Loop through database table and compare user input

Tags: mysql, c

I am trying to loop through the rows in a MySql table and compare the data in a certain column to some user input using C. Currently my code looks like this:

```
MYSQL *cxn = mysql_init(NULL);
MYSQL_RES *result;
unsigned int num_fields;
unsigned int num_rows;
char *query_string;
MYSQL_ROW *row;

if (mysql_real_connect(cxn, <em>/*blah blah blah**/</em>) == NULL) {
  printf("Please restart the service.");
}

result = mysql_store_result(cxn);
num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result);
num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

while (row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) {
  for (i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) {
    //Confusion occurring here
    //if (field[i] @ currentRow == "User input")
    //  printf("Win");
  }
}
```

Comment: Whatever the `@` is doing in C, you cannot compare string values with an `==` in C. You need a library function such as `strcmp` or a home-made function.

Comment: The '@' and everything else in the commented lines is just pseudo code.

Comment: Why would you iterate through an SQL database to look for something? Use SELECT to find it immediately and let the SQL engine do its work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only looking for fields that match the input, you'll want to search the database using the input string. In other words, write your query string so that it only gives you results that match the user input. This will be much faster than searching through every returned row for your user input.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE Cars=input`

If you do need every row to be returned, then you would want your code to read something like this

```
while (row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) {
  for (i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) {
    //Confusion occurring here
    //if (row[i] == "User input") You can't compare strings in C with ==
    if(strcmp(row[i], user_input) == 0))
      printf("Win");
  }
}
```

If your user input is a string, however, you'll want to compare using `strcmp`.

```
if(strcmp(row[i], user_input) == 0))
```

Comment: I am looking to compare the data in a pre-specified field. Like if the user types in "Mustang" I want to go look under "Car" and compare all values under "Car" for that string.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to only compare a specific column? Is "Car" a column header?

Comment: I want to compare all the data entries in the specified column to a user inputted string.

Comment: Could you solve the issue by structuring your query statement like this: `SELECT * FROM \`table\` WHERE Car=input`?

Comment: It's a good thing to remember that SQL will almost always be faster when searching through data than your own written looped search. Always try to root through data in your query rather than trying to find it in a loop.